# Data from the txt file were not read and/or showed the wrong corresponding values

Tags: c++

I was trying to create a simple game using C++ wherein a user was tasked to answer a problem within a given time. The problems and the answers are in the txt file but unfortunately, the program can only read one problem from the txt file and gives an incorrect answer. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int quickmath()
{
    int id, fileid, numInput, answer;
    string problem; 
    int i=0;

    int idarr[5];

    for (i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {
        idarr[i]= rand()%5;
    }
    do
    {       
        cout << endl << endl << "-----------------------------" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Timer: 7 sec"<<endl;
        ifstream outquick;
        outquick.open("quick.txt");
        idarr[i] = id;

        while (outquick >> fileid >> problem >> answer)
        {
            if (fileid == id)
            {
                cout << problem<< endl;
            }
        }

    }
    while (i<5);

    cout << "Answer: ";

    clock_t start = clock();
    while (!_kbhit())
    {
        if (((clock () - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 7) 
        {
            system("CLS");
            quick();
            cout << endl << endl << "-----------------------------" << endl << endl;
            cout << "TIME IS OUT!" << endl << endl;

            system("PAUSE");
            quickheader();
            break;                      
        }
    }

    cin >> numInput;

    if (numInput == answer)
    {
        cout << "Correct" << endl;
        quickmath();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Incorrect!" << endl << endl;
        system ("PAUSE");
        quickheader();
    }
    getch();    
}
```

Here is what in the txt file:

```
0 7+4 11

1 1+8 9

2 2*3 6

3 5*6 30

4 9-2 7
```

The output is :
7+4=____
Answer: 11
Incorrect

but if I enter 7, it shows Correct.

And  that was also the only problem that always appear.
Sorry, I was just a beginner :(

Comment: What is the output you expected from the shown file? What is the output you get? Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: There are a few problems in your code though. For starters the loop where you initialize `idarr`, which will go out of bounds of the array. And you never reset `i` anywhere so it will still be out of bounds when you use it in the next loop as index into `idarr`.

Comment: Ask yourself why you have two loops, a while loop inside a do while loop. Reading data from a file only requires one loop.

Comment: Look at the `id` variable, you use that variable in a couple of places but where do you ever give it a value? I think when you wrote `idarr[i] = id;` you probably meant `id = idarr[i];`

Comment: There are lots of other issues, to be honest I would start again, and write your code **slowly**. Write a few lines at a time, and test everything as you go. You written too much code and have multiple errors which means it's very difficult to fix the code.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, it is for our project and I was just a beginner. Ill try again my best to fix it :)